# Rspec fails but behaviour works when I test it via controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

This should be very simple to test, but for some reason my test is failing, please consider the following, model bit:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 

  def active!
    update_attribute(:active, true)
  end

end
```

controller :

```
def activate
    user = User.find_by_uuid(params[:id])
    user.active!

    puts "id #{user.id}"
end
```

test :

```
describe 'activate user' do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before do
        sign_in user
        visit activate_user_path(id: user.uuid)
        puts "id #{user.id}"
      end

      it 'should be true' do
        save_and_open_page
        user.active.should be_true
      end
end
```

This test fails :

```
expected: true value
            got: false
```

But when I do it with browser, the user gets activated without problems. What am I doing wrong? This really looks like a sily test but still doesn't pass, I've spend more than one hour trying out different stuff, none of which worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the spec still holds the `User` in the `user` variable that was created via FactoryGirl and does not know that is was changed in the database. Just reload the `user` and it should work:

```
it 'should be true' do
  save_and_open_page
  user.reload.active.should be_true
end
```

Btw. if `active` is a boolean you can also spec it this way (what reads much nicer):

```
user.reload.should be_active
```